# Как получить таблицу из docx в rust?

Tags: rust, docx

Крейт `docx`:

```
let document = DocxFile::from_file(raw_file__entity).unwrap().parse().unwrap();
let table = document.document.body.content.  // и где таблица-то???
```

как мне достать таблицу?